# Micrometer Metrics Missing for External Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, micrometer

I have a spring boot application deployed on the external apache tomcat 9.0.13 and using the micro meter to collect metrics for the application. I am able to see all the metrics except the tomcat metrics are missing. Is it possible to have metrics for external tomcat. If yes then what kind of configuration I would need to enable it.